# Parsing json data in Mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I am using Mysql version as follows:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"
    ->
    -> ;
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.26                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.6.26                       |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | osx10.8                      |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have a table named `tag` and inside it, I have a `text` column named`tagconfig`. This column has JSON data as stored as string as the following:

```
 { "option":{ "secure":"0" , "onetime":"0" , "rtmp":"1" , "hls":"0" , "http":"0" } , "video":[{ "format":"mp4" , "codec":"h264" , "bitrate":"800" , "width":"" , "height":"" , "fps":"" , "audiocodec":"mp3" , "audiobitrate":"96" }] }
```

I want to find the number of elements inside the `video` array in the json data.

I tried using `common_schema` like the following:

```
SELECT common_schema.get_option(be.tagconfig,'option') as t
from tag be LIMIT 200;
```

However, I get all the values as `null`. Preferable I want to create another column which has the number of elements in the `video` array in the json data. Is there a direct way in mysql to do this?

Comment: Better do this job in application level. Parsing json data in `MySQL` is too cumbersome!

Comment: Unless you upgrade it to 5.7 which has already built in json functions.

Answer (score 0):

`common_schema` has another function called `extract_json_value` function that can achieve exactly what you need here. It it better used from complex json object like the one you have. Under the hood it uses the `json_to_xml` function to convert the json to xml format and allows the use of xpaths to traverse through the object

```
SELECT common_schema.extract_json_value(be.tagconfig, 'count(//video)') as COUNT
```

the above query should get you what you need